# Which is the best way to load google fonts in web server for improved page load performance and to minimize Critical Requests Depth?

Tags: fonts, webfonts, google-pagespeed

Suggest the most effective way of loading google fonts in website. My priority is load improve page speed performance. Should i host google fonts locally or the other way ? Currently i had hosted fonts locally and it is increasing critical request depth.

Answer (score 0):

Download basic CSS from Googleapis.com:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700&display=swap
```

Save the file right into your theme directory so it’s like now:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/fonts.css
```

When you open `fonts.css` file, there is content which looks like this:

```
/* latin-ext */
 @font-face {
   font-family: 'Montserrat';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-display: swap;
   src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v15/JTUSjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459Wdhyzbi.woff2) format('woff2');
   unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
 }
...
```

Save font from “url” in newly created folder “fonts” in your theme and replace path in fonts.css so it’s now:

```
src: url(wp-content/themes/theme-name/fonts/JTUSjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459Wdhyzbi.woff2) format('woff2');
```

In my case, there were 60+ fonts to download :-) (so I wrote simple php downloader).

Last step is to add `fonts.css` to your theme's code in the header part:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="local-fonts-css" href="https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/fonts.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

That are the basics how to locally host Google fonts.

[Source](https://www.jasom.net/host-google-fonts-locally-in-wordpress-theme/)